# How to redirect non extension to extension page

Tags: php, .htaccess

My website is in php. When I open the url without any extension, I want to redirect to its original extension page.
Ex: when user types the follwoing url

`www.abc.com/contact`

I want to redirect to the original page

`www.abc.com/contact.html`

In htaccess I tried this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

But this is not redirecting. It's just removing html.

So question is: how can I redirect to .html pages when user is not typing the file extension?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below .htaccess code :

```
Redirect 301 /contact www.abc.com/contact.html
```

For multiple files just try the below code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: is there any dynamic coding in htaccess?

Comment: did not get by 'dynamic' code?we have to give as rule to make it happen

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

or

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .html extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html[NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html[L]
```